# Is it possible to add a combobox as column in a listbox in VBA?

Tags: forms, vba, excel, combobox, listbox

Using a VBA form, is it possible to add a Listbox control that has columns which contain Combo box controls? [image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like a [datagridview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) that can have controls in the cells? Can you dedicate a portion of the spreadsheet itself to this task since you can do what your're looking to do with Excel natively?

Comment: Yes, something like a datagridview.  The requirement is that the table/columns need to display on an existing VBA form, so unfortunately, we can't do it in the spreadsheet itself.

Comment: Perhaps you have them created in userform but those extra ones are only **Visible** when certain conditions are met with the other Controls' value?

Comment: @MatthewWalk what exactly do you want to have displayed/changed?

Answer (score 1):

No not possible with `Standard VBA`; `Standard VBA` will not allow this! You may be able to create a custom `ActivX control` or load another 3rd party control as suggested elsewhere but a standard `ListBox` cannot hold a `ComboBox`.

Other Workarounds may be usable if you can provide more details...

Answer (score 0):

If you insist in doing that using User Forms, the only way is that when you click a list item, it should pop a different form containing the combo box, it will be too much work to create and difficult to maintain.

I am sure with spreadsheet itself you can come up with better solutions. I am still not sure what ultimately you want to achieve, but to me this is just a dependent list so you can use sth like this in the spreadsheet itself:

http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html